# Column created as Case When result is not working in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter values based on the dynamically created column but which is not working,Please help me to proceed further.

```
SELECT proj.is_active,pal.Project_Artifact_Id,
       CASE WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('Closed', 'Verified','Rejected')
                THEN  'COM'
            WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') 
                 AND (pal.due_date = getDate() OR pal.due_date = (Getdate()+2))
                THEN  'OD'
            WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') AND pal.due_date > (Getdate()+2)
                THEN  'CR'
       END AS Filter_Status
FROM Project_Artifact_List pal,
     Projects proj 
WHERE proj.project_code = pal.Project_Code
  AND Filter_Status IN ('CR');
```

***Update***

```
invalid column name error message comes
```

Comment: you can't filter like that,use CTE or derived table

Comment: Thanks all for your replies and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access column aliases in the where clause. First wrap your query up in a derived table:

```
select *
from
(  
    SELECT proj.is_active,pal.Project_Artifact_Id,
           CASE WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('Closed', 'Verified','Rejected')
                    THEN  'COM'
                WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') 
                     AND (pal.due_date = getDate() OR pal.due_date = (Getdate()+2))
                    THEN  'OD'
                WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') AND pal.due_date > (Getdate()+2)
                    THEN  'CR'
           END AS Filter_Status
    FROM Project_Artifact_List pal,
         Projects proj 
    WHERE proj.project_code = pal.Project_Code    
) dt
WHERE Filter_Status IN ('CR');
```

Comment: I tried this but says incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE

Comment: @sunleo - Did you add the alias name `dt` after the derived table ? Answer is perfectly valid. Also start using `INNER JOIN` instead of old style comma separated join

Comment: That dt table alias isn't needed according to ANSI SQL, but required by some dbms products.

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte as
(

    SELECT proj.is_active,pal.Project_Artifact_Id,
           CASE WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('Closed', 'Verified','Rejected')
                    THEN  'COM'
                WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') 
                     AND (pal.due_date = getDate() OR pal.due_date = (Getdate()+2))
                    THEN  'OD'
                WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') AND pal.due_date > (Getdate()+2)
                    THEN  'CR'
           END AS Filter_Status
    FROM Project_Artifact_List pal,
         Projects proj 
    WHERE proj.project_code = pal.Project_Code

)
select * from cte
WHERE Filter_Status IN ('CR')
```

Comment: Works well, Thanks

Comment: Will it work as single query for JDBC call?, normally single sql we used to have.

Answer (score 1):

CASE depends solely on Project_Artifact_List, you can use CROSS APPLY to compute Filter_Status so it's recognized in WHERE

```
SELECT proj.is_active,pal.Project_Artifact_Id,       
FROM Project_Artifact_List pal
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
           CASE WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('Closed', 'Verified','Rejected')
                THEN  'COM'
            WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') 
                 AND (pal.due_date = getDate() OR pal.due_date = (Getdate()+2))
                THEN  'OD'
            WHEN pal.artifact_status IN ('In Progress') AND pal.due_date > (Getdate()+2)
                THEN  'CR'
       END AS Filter_Status) fs 
   , Projects proj
WHERE proj.project_code = pal.Project_Code
  AND fs.Filter_Status IN ('CR');
```